# Conditional Left Join in MySQL without Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join

I have two tables, X and Y :

```
mysql> select * from X;
+------+------+
| id   | colX |
+------+------+
| 2001 |    0 |
| 2002 |    0 |
| 2003 |    0 |
| 2004 |    0 |
| 2005 |    0 |
| 2006 |   10 |
| 2007 |   10 |
+------+------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM Y;
+------+------+-------+
| id   | colY | score |
+------+------+-------+
| 2001 |   10 |     3 |
| 2004 |    0 |    12 |
| 2005 |    0 |    15 |
| 2007 |    0 |     1 |
+------+------+-------+
```

I need the following result but without the subquery :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id WHERE colX=0 AND X.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Y WHERE colY > 0);
+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | colX | id   | colY | score |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2002 |    0 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2003 |    0 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2004 |    0 | 2004 |    0 |    12 |
| 2005 |    0 | 2005 |    0 |    15 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

- colX must be 0
- if id is present in table Y and colY = 0 then give corresponding score
- if id is not present in table Y give score = NULL

I tried the following query but id 2001 shows up :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id AND Y.colY = 0 WHERE colX=0;
+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | colX | id   | colY | score |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 2001 |    0 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2002 |    0 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2003 |    0 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2004 |    0 | 2004 |    0 |    12 |
| 2005 |    0 | 2005 |    0 |    15 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM X LEFT JOIN
     Y
     ON X.id = Y.id 
WHERE x.colX = 0 AND (Y.colY = 0 OR Y.colY IS NULL)
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.